# Mojave plist error: Path had bad ownership/permissions

Tags: launchd, mojave, mount, plist

I'm trying to mount a fileshare at boot.  I copied the plist from a 2012 mini (where it ran fine) to a 2018 mini, both running Mojave. On the new mini I'm getting the error:

```
 Path had bad ownership/permissions

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.mount.video</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/sbin/mount_smbfs</string>
        <string>smb://jeff:mypass@bignas1/video</string>
        <string>/Volumes/home/jeff/bignas1/video</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The plist is user-owned (501) with permissions of 0600, same as on the 2012 mini. The directory where the share is mounted is 501-owned as well, with permissions of 0755. The plist is located at ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

If I move the plist to /Library/LaunchAgents and exec it as root the share mounts as expected, but only root can access it.

What am I missing here?  Everything online points to a permission/ownership problem, but I don't see the issue here.

Comment: you have that file set as Run at Load ?

Comment: Yes. <key>RunAtLoad</key>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. On the new Mac Mini my primary storage is a RAID array of SSDs in a Thunderbolt enclosure. This external storage was marked as ignore ownership.  So, even though it appeared to me to have correct ownership and permissions, when viewed as root everything was owner _unknown,  group _unknown.

When ignore owner was turned off and the proper ownership was applied everything was functional again.